# Maven transitive dependency not being deployed in TeamCity

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, maven-3

I have a small maven web project. Its pom includes dependencies to other libraries. One of them has a dependency to slf4j-api.

When running maven's `clean install` from inside IntelliJ IDEA the resulting war file includes slf4j-api.jar in WEB-INF/lib

Now we have configured a TeamCity maven build for the project. It builds without any errors, but it doesn't include this specific transitive dependency (whereas it includes others).

Do you have any general hints to why this might happen?

Currently we added the dependency directly to the main pom even though we don't need it there...

In the main pom

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>xxxxxxxxx</groupId>
   <artifactId>mylibrary</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.20</version>
</dependency>
```

in *mylibrary*'s pom

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I haven't specified any scope, so I suppose it's `compile` in any case.

Comment: Without your pom it's more or less impossible to say...I assume that the dependency has given scope `provided`?

Comment: please see latest edit